# Can i find nearest location from my current location

Tags: javascript, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm wondering that is there any method to find nearest locations like Hospital, bus Stop,gym etc..

PS: I'm using MySQL DB and only current location lat long will be stored in my DB i should get all nearest locations lat long from API

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1):

You have to use the REST Google Places API.

"Nearby Search Requests"

Example:
GET https://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/place/nearbysearch/json?location=-33.8670522,151.1957362&radius=500&types=food&name=cruise&key=AddYourOwnKeyHere

[Documentation here](https://developers.google.com/places/documentation/search)

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes.

Comment: @AnttiHaapala the link IS the answer in this case, not just a link to a website that shows how to do it.  If the link changes, the answer would also become invalid, even if Suxxa gave more detail.

Comment: The *essential parts better to include* are small excerpts from the documentation, not the GET URL.

Comment: the above link is giving me error  >"The provided API key is invalid."

Comment: Hope that i need to get API key 
can i achieve this with out API key ??
i worked on Google map without using Key

Comment: Visit the Google APIs Console at https://code.google.com/apis/console and log in with your Google account. You can use the default projet or create your own. Once register, you can use your own key in the url parameters (key=...)

All steps here: https://developers.google.com/places/documentation

Comment: Sorry if I'm wrong 
I got Api key for my unique IP after adding that key on url 
I got below page 
{
   "error_message" : "This IP, site or mobile application is not authorized to use this API key.",
   "html_attributions" : [],
   "results" : [],
   "status" : "REQUEST_DENIED"
}